# What cause this error?

Tags: ip, docker, hadoop, host

I am running two docker containers one is for hadoop basic services and other is for flume. Services are running successfully. I linked two containers env variables are automatically set by docker successfully.

```
1.2.3.4    7ab4ffb30dc0
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback

fe00::0 ip6-localnet
```

This is My /etc/hosts file for hadoop. When i run

```
hadoop fs -ls /
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://127.0.0.1:8020/
```

Works fine. But if i run

```
hostname
```

it returns 7ab4ffb30dc0

So i tried

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://1.2.3.4:8020/
```

it says Call From 7ab4ffb30dc0/1.2.3.4 to 7ab4ffb30dc0:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Any suggestions?

Hello, I learned from that site

These are the directions which i learened to tackle serverfault problem

```
  telnet localhost
```

says `connection refused`. it tried to connect to 127.0.0.1 and 0::

```
  telnet feorar.org
```

works so telent daemon is running

```
  telnet localhost 44444
```

says `Trying ::1...
      Connected to localhost.
      Escape character is '^]'.
      Connection closed by foreign host.`
but

```
  netstat -tna
```

says service is listening at :::44444

```
  telnet localhost 25
```

works. there is an entry for port 25.

I don't understand what's the difference between :::44444 and ::1:25 under localhost of netstat -tna 's output.
Any help?

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Answer (score 6):

#### My suggestion is to read the information provided.

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;

This generally means nothing is listening on the specified IP:Port.

Note also this information is provided

> http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

and it's first line

> You get a ConnectionRefused Exception when there is a machine at the address specified, but there is no program listening on the specific TCP port the client is using -and there is no firewall in the way silently dropping TCP connection requests.

There is more information in the helpful link too, you should read it.

#### Please be bothered to read the information provided before wasting the internet's time.